# GridLayout SurfaceView children overlays each other when changing the visibility of them

Tags: java, android, surfaceview, grid-layout, android-gridlayout

I have an activity named `ScreensActivity`, this activity contains a `GridLayout`.

Each of the `GridLayout` children is a custom `View` named `ScreenView`.

`ScreenView` consist of a `SurfaceView` which intended to play video from a .MP4 file.

This is the view hierarchy of the above mentioned components:

```
ScreensActivity
    GridLayout
        ScreenView
        ScreenView
        ScreenView
        ScreenView
        ...
```

**Expected Behavior**

What I am trying to do is to add support for changing the "state" of a `ScreenView` in the `GridLayout` to "full-screen", by *disappearing* (using `setVisibility(GONE)`) the rest of the `ScreenView`'s, so it will fill the entire `GridLayout`.

Only one `ScreenView` at a time can be in "full-screen state"

**Current Behavior**

Currently, this is only working when attempting to change the "state" of the 1st `ScreenView` in the `GridLayout` (which is the expected behavior).

When attempting to change the "state" from the 2nd `ScreenView` and so on, I encounter the following weird behavior (see **[visual GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwJyh.jpg)** of the examples below):

When changing a `ScreenView` "state" to "full-screen", it **being overlaid** by other `ScreenView`'s, for example:

- When changing the 2nd `ScreenView` "state" to "full-screen", the 1st `ScreenView` *overlays* him.
- When changing the 3rd `ScreenView` "state" to "full-screen", both the 1st and the 2nd "screens *overlay* him, and so on.
- And so on, until changing the 9th `ScreenView` "state" to "full-screen", all the previous `ScreenView`'s overlay him.

**Important Note**

When I replace the `SurfaceView` (inside the `ScreenView`) with `TextView`, for example, changing the `ScreenView` "state" to "full-screen" executes as expected, so it seems that the problematic component which produce this weird behavior is the `SurfaceView` which the `ScreenView` consist of.

Let me know if adding the source code will help you solve my issue.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: you better change your approach, SurfaceViews are unlike normal views, in fact, they are like a "hole" that is filled by underlying native code. You will probably find all kind of artifacts, even different accross devices, if you use multiple surfaceviews, overlapping surfaceviews, etc... Also, your application will consume a lot of resources.

Comment: @rupps what do you suggest then?

Comment: i don't know what to suggest, as you are probably facing limitations of the lowlevel phone video driver. I'd suggest you to try on some other devices. If you see different behaviour (I bet you will), I'd just give up the idea and try to use only one surfaceview (the active video playing) and change the rest to an image. Also, you could try to physically moving the supposedly hidden surfaceviews out of the screen (as Visibility.GONE is related to the "normal" part of the view that gets out of sync with the real surface)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by replacing the `SurfaceView` with a [TextureView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html) which behaves exactly how I expected it to behave.